# Adding a Gtk::ListStore to Gtk::TreeView and adding rows to ListStore (gtkmm)

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I want to be able to add a Gtk::ListStore to a Gtk::TreeView, the treeview was implemented through glade but I have created the ListStore in C++ and added columns and rows to it.

When I run the code it shows the window and the tree_view that has been loaded from the glade file but it is empty.

mainWindow.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <gtkmm.h>


class MainWindow {
    protected:
        Gtk::Window *main_window;

        Gtk::TreeView *tree_view;
        Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::ListStore> list_store;

    public:
        void init();

        class ModelColumns : public Gtk::TreeModel::ColumnRecord
        {
        public:
            ModelColumns() { add(name); add(age); }

            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Glib::ustring> name;
            Gtk::TreeModelColumn<Glib::ustring> age;
        };
};
```

mainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainWindow.h"

void MainWindow::init() {

    auto app = Gtk::Application::create("org.gtkmm.example");
    auto builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("test.glade");

    builder->get_widget("main_window", main_window);
    builder->get_widget("tree_view", tree_view);

    ModelColumns columns;

    list_store = Gtk::ListStore::create(columns);
    tree_view->set_model(list_store);

    Gtk::TreeModel::Row row = *(list_store->append());
    row[columns.name] = "John";
    row[columns.age] = "30";

    row = *(list_store->append());
    row[columns.name] = "Lisa";
    row[columns.age] = "27";

    app->run(*main_window);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainWindow.h"


int main() {
    MainWindow m;
    m.init();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
tree_view->set_model(list_store);
```

tells `tree_view` to use `list_store` as its TreeModel, but it does not say what column from the `list_store` to render. In fact, the default behavior is that no column would be rendered.

To render both columns, you need to ask `tree_view` to append them.

```
// "Name" is column title, columns.name is data in the list_store      
tree_view->append_column("Name", columns.name);                              
tree_view->append_column("Age", columns.age);
```

Gtkmm has an official tutorial book. This is the section on treeview.  https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-treeview.html.en